# WCF connection timeout when trying to connect to an unreachable host

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I set connection timeout the following way:

```cs
var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None, true);
binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
```

Then I try to connect to the service like this:

```cs
var client = new ServiceClient(new InstanceContext(eventClient), binding, address);
client.Subscribe();
```

Whenever the client attempts to connect to a reachable host but without the service running it will timeout in 5 seconds like I expect it to. When the client attempts to connect to an unreachable host it freezes for 15-20 seconds or so.

Is there any way to make it timeout faster?

Comment: Pause the debugger during the 15sec wait and post the full stack. This can give a clue to what component needs to be configured.